# eclipse does not read code

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, refresh

I am new in using Eclipse and I am facing many problems. The first is that if I write an instruction wrong - for instance: `android:layout_height="wrap_contet"` and not `content` - the `IDE` does not visualize any error and this is very annoying. 
If I change the dimensions in the *values resources* the picture does not update in the *render preview*. I need to close the program an restart it, just then the picture gets updated.

It is like the `IDE` is just ignoring half of the things that I write down. I click on F5 many times to refresh but nothing gets refreshed.
First I used Android Studio and I did not have these problems.

Comment: The issues will show up at least if you try to build and run the project.

Comment: You have problem with Eclipse  ??

Comment: If Android Studio/IntelliJ works for you, why don't you stay with it? Most of the tutorials were written for Eclipse ADT, but it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the instructions for Eclipse ADT to Android Studio.

Comment: So for every change to my layout I need to build and run? Then what is the sense of a render preview?

Answer (score 0):

Try This go to Project->Clean, it will provide an Updated version of your project.

Comment: wat exactly is your issue..??

Comment: are you trying to use a picture in your app..??

Answer (score 0):

First if you are using Windows then go to Window->Android Virtual Device. After you start your AVD you will get your first issue solved regarding wrong instruction it will show error on the left after saving the xml file.i need more info on your second issue.

[image]